# Replace RegExp named captured group in Sublime Text & Visual Studio Code

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, sublimetext

I would like to do the replacement of the named capture group in these two IDE, Sublime Text and Visual Studio Code. And, I actually succeed in using IntelliJ WebStorm.

An example corpus was:

```
Title: Hamlet
Genre: Tragedy
Playwright: Williams Shakespere

Title: Woyzeck
Genre: Tragedy
Playwright: Karl Georg Büchner
```

and I used the following RegEx to retrieve the playwright

```regex
Playwright: (?<playwright>.*)
```

and replace this with the following RegEx to wrap in an XML format for the further analysis

```regex
<playwright>${playwright}</playwright>
```

Both Sublime Text and Visual Studio Code failed with this outcome:

```xml
Title: Hamlet
Genre: Tragedy
<playwright>${playwright}</playwright>

Title: Woyzeck
Genre: Tragedy
<playwright>${playwright}</playwright>
```

While WebStorm delivered the right results

Does anyone know how to make it with these two IDEs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SublimeText, the replacement pattern [can contain](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/accessing-named-regex-groups-in-find-replace/13420/2) [named backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) and should look like

```
<playwright>$+{playwright}</playwright>
```

In Visual Studio Code, named backreferences are [not supported](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/88793) in the replacement patterns (the feature request did not collect enough community upvotes).

Comment: Thanks, `$+{group_name}` in Sublime Text really worked.